# Android AlertDialog show() after hide()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a trouble with `AlertDialog`. If i will call `dialog.show()` after `dialog.hide()` it will not be shown, but if I call `dialog.show()` again, all ok. If i call `dialog.show()` twice in a row, dialog showing always.

And If replace `hide() -> dismiss()` it is ok allways. But in my case i need to use `hide()` to save the dialog.

**SAMPLE**

```
AlertDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Text")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialogInterface, which) -> onYesClicked())
        .create();
    Button login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.show());
}

private void onYesClicked() {
    dialog.hide();
}
```

**EDITED: SOLUTION**

```
private void onYesClicked() {
    new Handler().post(() -> dialog.hide());
}
```

Comment: Provide some code of yours.

Comment: Why do you need to "save" the dialog though?

Comment: For implement simple data saving and fast restore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Method `hide()` it is useless to call when a button (created by `AlerdDialog.Builder`) is clicked. Because system send MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG and automatically call `dismiss()` for this dialog:

**SDK code:**

```
        // Post a message so we dismiss after the above handlers are executed
        mHandler.obtainMessage(ButtonHandler.MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG, mDialogInterface)
                .sendToTarget();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use, hide(), it may lead to Leaked Window error. Please have a look: [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Using dismiss() and save the message/title instead of the whole dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hide and show the dialog again, try this code:

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

when you call hide, and call show, the callback will be invoke.

Comment: Thanks, it really work. But it looks like to call `dialog.show()` twice in a row. But I found a better solution: `new Handler().post(() -> dialog.hide())`

Answer (score 0):

try this to make the dialog pop up just once:

```
 if (dialog != null && dialog.getDialog() != null
                                && dialog.getDialog().isShowing()) {
                     //Leave Empty here or your way
}else{
 code to open a dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in onYesClicked() method used below code ..

```
private void onYesClicked() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        // Showing message with a timer.
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.hide();
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```